# normal form question

Tags: group-theory

Consider the free product $\langle a \rangle\ast\langle b \rangle$, with $a$ and $b$ of order $p$ odd prime. Let $a_i = b^{-i} a b^i$ and $C=\langle a_i \colon 0 < i \leq p-1\rangle$. I have to prove that 
$$
a_{i_1}^{s_1}\dots a_{i_h}^{s_h}
$$
is a normal form for elements in $C$
[ADD: here $i_n\neq i_{n+1}$].

My idea was to consider an element in $C$ obtained in two different ways
$$
a_{i_1}^{s_1}\dots a_{i_h}^{s_h}=a_{j_1}^{t_1}\dots a_{j_k}^{t_k}
$$
and prove that the writings are the same.
So, expand both sides
$$
b^{-i_1}a^{s_1}(b^{i_1}b^{-i_2})a^{s_2}(b^{i_2}b^{-i_3})\cdots=b^{-j_1}a^{s_1}(b^{j_1}b^{-j_2})\cdots;
$$

we can see that adjacent terms are first in $\langle b \rangle$ 
and then in $\langle a \rangle$ and so on, so at left hand side there is a member of $P$ (a free product) in normal form. Hence the expressions in $a$ and $b$ must coincide, then backwards we obtain that the $i$ and the $j$ indices are the same, as well as the $s$ and $t$ indices.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: It looks roughly right to me, but I think you need to assume that $i_j \ne i_{j+1}$, otherwise two adjacent terms could combine, or even cancel, and the original expression would not be in normal form.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that hypothesis. I edited the original message.